# Flink Pojo serializer showing a lot of CPU time spent in KryoException<init>

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, kryo

I used to have a `POJO` being sent from one vertex to another using a `HASH` connector, and never noticed anything weird in the `Flame Graphs` view.

I have now added an `AsyncIO` step that will do the `keyBy` operation after some external operations and now the Flame Graphs show a large amount of time spent in some sort of serialization exception that I don't understand.

The `POJO` is exactly the same as it used to be. The only "change" is that previously there were operations that took much longer than the serialization, and now since most of the time we don't need any external lookup this step becomes some sort of passthrough operation.

It has getters and setters for all the fields, empty constructor, and even an explicit `TypeInformation` class field:

```java
public class MyObject {
    public static final TypeInformation< MyObject > TYPE_INFORMATION = Types.POJO(MyObject.class,
ImmutableMap.of("field1", Types.STRING,
"protobufField2",TypeInformation.of(ProtoClass1OuterClass.ProtoClass1.class),
"protobufField3",TypeInformation.of(ProtoClass1OuterClass.ProtoClass2.class),
"pojo2", Types.POJO(Pojo2.class)));

    private String field1;
    private ProtoClass1OuterClass.ProtoClass1 protobufField2;
    private ProtoClass1OuterClass.ProtoClass2 protobufField3;
    private Pojo2 pojo2;

    public MyObject() {
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public ProtoClass1OuterClass.ProtoClass1 getProtobufField2() {
        return protobufField2;
    }

    public void setProtobufField2(ProtoClass1OuterClass.ProtoClass1 protobufField2) {
        this.protobufField2 = protobufField2;
    }

    public ProtoClass1OuterClass.ProtoClass2 getProtobufField3() {
        return protobufField3;
    }

    public void setProtobufField3(ProtoClass1OuterClass.ProtoClass2 protobufField3) {
        this.protobufField3 = protobufField3;
    }

    public Pojo2 getPojo2() {
        return pojo2;
    }

    public void setPojo2(Pojo2 pojo2) {
        this.pojo2 = pojo2;
    }
}
```

Then Pojo2 is a class like the following:

```java
public abstract class Pojo2 implements Serializable {

    byte[] data;

    public Pojo2() {
        // POJO
    }

    protected Pojo2(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public abstract String function(String param);

    // POJO
    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    // POJO
    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    // More functions
}
```

All the types and subtypes are registered as well:

```java
config.registerPojoType(Pojo2.class);
config.registerPojoType(Pojo2Child.class);
config.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(ProtoClass1OuterClass.class, ProtobufSerializer.class);
config.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(ProtoClass1.class, ProtobufSerializer.class);
config.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(ProtoClass2.class, ProtobufSerializer.class);
```

**Flame Graphs Screenshot:**
[image: Flame Graphs Screenshot]

Comment: Could you add some additional information about your specific POJO and what your job graph looks like? Have you considered setting something like `disableGenericTypes()` on your job which should force an exception if a given serialization would fallback to Kryo and possibly some more details on where this bottleneck is stemming from.

Comment: When I disable generic types serialization I get an exception for a Protobuf field for which I have a serializer registered:
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Generic types have been disabled in the ExecutionConfig and type ProtoField is treated as a generic type.`
I registered the serializer like this:
`config.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(ProtoField.class, ProtobufSerializer.class);
`

Comment: The POJO structure is already defined in the original post

Comment: I was more asking of what the actual `MyObject` object looked like - as your explicitly registering those fields, but it's possible that there are other underlying issues. You may need to explicitly register that class to indicate it'll be deserialized via Protobuf via a `.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(MyObject.class,ProtobufSerializer.class)` call.

Comment: I have added more details to the original post. `MyObject` itself is not a protobuf, it's a `POJO` that contains protobuf fields. Do I need to register `MyObject` as protobuf?